# Using array_map to make an alternative to print_r to produce a 'cleaner' output

Tags: php, array-map

I need a cleaner output than print_r gives me

an array like

```
$array = array(1,2,3,"four"=>array(4.1,4.2));
```

should print out somthing like this

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
[four]
0: 4.1
1: 4.2
```

I've come up with this, but the array_map does not return what I expected

```
function print_array($array) {
    $string = "";

    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        if (is_array ( $value )) {
            $string .= "[" . $key . "]\r\n" . array_map ( 'print_array', $value );
        } else {
            $string .= $key . ": " . $value . "\r\n";
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

The output from this is

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
[four]
Array
```

my array_map use is apparently wrong can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this it may help you , call your function recursively if value is an array.

```
<?php 

function print_array($array) {
    $string = "";
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        if (is_array ( $value )) {
            $string .= "[" . $key . "]\r\n" . print_array($value );
        } else {
            $string .= $key . ": " . $value . "\r\n";
        }
    }
    return $string;
}

$array = array(1,2,3,"four"=>array(4.1,4.2));
print_r(print_array($array));
?>
```

#### Output

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
[four]
0: 4.1
1: 4.2
```

Comment: Yes of course thank you. Sometimes you just get blinded by a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

This way of printing doesn't really need  `array_map`. The following uses the biggest part of your own function. It is untested but should help you in the right direction.

```
function print_array($source) {
    $string = "";
    foreach ($sorce as $key => value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $string .= $key . ": array (\r\n";
            $string .= print_array($value);
            $string .= ")\r\n";
        } else {
            $string .= $key . ": " . $value . "\r\n";
        }
    }

    return $string;
}

echo print_array($myArray);
```